# WPF Application with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

How do I insert an image in a database and retrieve the image in Crystal Reports using a C# WPF Application?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Windows Form Integration tools to use Crystal with WPF. There are no native support tools in WPF for Crystal. Once you're using the WFI namespace, the Crystal controls work the same as they would in WinForms.

Comment: Do you know of any third party solutions to incorporate crystal reports instead of using window forms integration?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports now supports WPF integration.
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-54328